# Local Mysql success login, but lost connection every run query

Tags: mysql

i have install mysql for a mont ago. i use every day without any problem. and now, my mysql very strange. i can login to mysql, and alway succees. but, sometime cannot run a query.

this is the sample of unseccessfull query:

```
gai@gai-Lenovo-G470 ~ $ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use sps;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server

mysql>
```

I am very confused. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Nobody wants backup... everybody wants restore...

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, The largest cause is usually just timeout issues, Do you get this error after a large amount of idle time?

If the command returns a large amount of data that is to large it can also cause the issue.

The various causes and fixes are listed [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) Please try the fixes and if you still have issues let us know what you have tried.

Comment: my data is very small. max allowed packet set 500M(just for debug). i dont need big data query. just like "show tables" and simple select query. the simple query sometime successfull and sometime failed with error connection. i run query in same machine with mysq-client. for this condition, i think my causes problem is not listed.

Comment: Are you accessing the server locally where it is hosted or over a network? Have you tried enabling logging level mentioned in the article to enable the capturing of some logout messages on the server?

Comment: i am accessed locally.